# Print in the 8 x 8 array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, printing, grid

Ok so I am having one of those "can't sleep, might as well program" kind of nights. As of right now I am probably just overtired, however, it is bugging me. I am trying to get my code to print the char[] options into the 8x8 array. I have my methods set up but it just ends up printing to another 8 x 8 array directly below my other 8 x 8 array. Warning this is porbably an extremley stupid mistake. However I seem to be oblivious to all my errors right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

'

```
static char[] options = {'*','$','@','+','!','&'};

public static void main(String[] args){ 

    System.out.println("How to play: type a row and column index, followed by \n" +
                        "the direction to move it: u (up), r (right), d (down), l (left)");     
    char[][] grid = new char[8][8];

    drawGrid(grid);
    populateRandom(grid,options);
    System.out.println("Enter <row> <column> <direction to move> or q to quit");
    //char randomChar = 66;
    //System.out.println(randomChar);
}

   public static void drawGrid(char[][] grid){

        System.out.println("\t1 \t2 \t3 \t4 \t5 \t6 \t7 \t8");
        System.out.println();
        //Random r = new Random();

        for(int row=0 ; row < grid.length ; row++) {
            //populateRandom(grid,options);
            System.out.print((row+1)+"");
            for(int column=0 ; column < grid[row].length ; column++){

                //populateRandom(grid, options);

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
            System.out.println();
    }

   public static void populateRandom(char[][] grid, char[] options) 
   {
   Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++){
       for (int column=0; column < grid[row].length; column++){

          int randomIndex = randomGenerator.nextInt(6);
          grid[row][column] = options[randomIndex];
          System.out.print("\t" + grid[row][column]);
       }
      System.out.println(); 

   }



   }

   public static boolean isWithinGrid (int row, int col, String cmd, char[][] grid) {
      return true;   
   }

   public static void swap (int row, int col, String cmd, char[][] grid){

   }

   public static boolean updateGrid (char[][] grid, char[] options) {
       return false;
   }
```

}

'

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The simplest I can think of is to remove the loops from the `populateRandom()` function (and maybe name it something else) and call it inside the inner most loop in `drawGrid()`

```
static char[] options = { '*', '$', '@', '+', '!', '&' };

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out
            .println("How to play: type a row and column index, followed by \n"
                    + "the direction to move it: u (up), r (right), d (down), l (left)");
    char[][] grid = new char[8][8];

    drawGrid(grid);
    System.out
            .println("Enter <row> <column> <direction to move> or q to quit");
    // char randomChar = 66;
    // System.out.println(randomChar);
}

public static void drawGrid(char[][] grid) {

    System.out.println("\t1 \t2 \t3 \t4 \t5 \t6 \t7 \t8");
    System.out.println();
    // Random r = new Random();

    for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        // populateRandom(grid,options);
        System.out.print((row + 1) + "");
        for (int column = 0; column < grid[row].length; column++) {

            populateRandom(grid[row][column]);

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void populateRandom(char grid) {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomIndex = randomGenerator.nextInt(6);
    grid = options[randomIndex];
    System.out.print("\t" + grid);

}

public static boolean isWithinGrid(int row, int col, String cmd,
        char[][] grid) {
    return true;
}

public static void swap(int row, int col, String cmd, char[][] grid) {

}

public static boolean updateGrid(char[][] grid, char[] options) {
    return false;
}
```

The problem with what you are doing is that, on console, once you go to a new line, you can't go back and print more stuff on the previous line (actually you can but it's really cumbersome and pointless).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i don't understand your problem...

you would like to see just one grid, isn't it?

Maybe you need to understand the concept of System.out
System.out is not a dynamic sheet that you can edit.
You just can write and write!! Append by append!

The only way to do this is to "clear the screen" and draw the grid again!
because You can't change the code generated in the output!

so try out this solution!
Insert this function in your program:

```
private static void Clear()
{
    try
    {
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name");

        if (os.contains("Windows"))
        {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
        }
        else
        {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
    }
}
```

than call this Clear() method function after the drawGrid() method, like this:

```
drawGrid(grid);
Clear();
populateRandom(grid,options);
```

anyway, have a look to the concept behind the output console!